# Cell shift in Excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I wrote the following python script that reads the contents of "prom output.csv" file, and after some processing it writes the output to the file "sorted output."

```
import collections
import csv
import sys

with open("prom output.csv","r") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
    d=collections.defaultdict(lambda : list())
    header=next(cr)   
    for r in cr:
        d[r[0]].append(r[1])  


with open("sorted output.csv","w") as f:
    cr = csv.writer(f,sys.stdout, lineterminator='\n')
    cr.writerow(header)  
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
    for k,v in od.items(): 
        cr.writerow([k,";".join(v)])
```

The output "sorted output.csv" looks like:

[image]

My input file: "prom output.csv"  looks like:

[image]

I want to slightly modify the current output so that it will have the following form:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `join` for your row content; just combine the header w/ the data into a single list:

```
cr.writerow([k]+v)
```